# IEnumerable<Mileage> doesn't contain definition for ExpMonthYr

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I added @model IEnumerable instead of @model TravelSOCC.Models.LansingMileage which will no longer allow me to access my ExpMonthYr

I know according to the documentation these two functions should be seperated as they are performing different task just was trying to make the end user have fewer pages to navigate.

What this is supposed to do is allow a user to select a date from the datepicker and then update the database and have it be re-displayed in a table using the `@foreach` this means that I need to be able to use both the `@Html.EditorFor` and the `@Foreach` within the same view but not within the same table.

```
    @model IEnumerable<TravelSOCC.Models.LansingMileage>

    <h3>STATE OFFICERS COMPENSATION COMMISSION (SOCC)</h3>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {

        <table class="table">
            <tr>
                <th>Senator Information</th>
                <th>Monthly Expense Summary</th>
                <th>Expense Month/Year</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>State Senator</td>
                <td>Mileage Total:<br />Expense Total:<br /><strong>Total:</strong></td>
                <!--This will become a datepicker-->
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpMonthYr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", Name = "expenseDate" } })</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    }
   <table id="LansingData" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Expense Month/Yr</th>
                <th>Travel Date</th>
                <th>Travel Type</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr id="">
                    <!--Here is where I will create a table to display my data from the above section-->
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Considering you have a list of `LansingMileage` objects, is your intent to loop over this list? I'd think you want to create a row for each record.

Comment: My intent is to have create a new row for each new entry. I had thought about the list to loop through, but not sold on it.

Comment: I think you want something like `@foreach (var x in model)` and wrap the table in that `foreach` with `{}`. Check [this tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/ASp/razor_cs_loops.asp).

Comment: @Joelius for this issue I'm wanting my table to stay the same, but I'm trying to use foreach(var item in Model){}  as well as the html.EditorFor which is not working given the IEnumerable.

Comment: In that case I will remove my answer and vote for this to be closed as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375295/using-editorfor-in-foreach-or-for-loop-asp-net-mvc-razor). Does this question help you?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using EditorFor in Foreach or For loop (ASP.NET MVC + RAZOR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36375295/using-editorfor-in-foreach-or-for-loop-asp-net-mvc-razor)

Comment: See that doesn't really answer the question as I'm not wanting to loop for the EditorFor. Instead I'm wanting to actuallyhave two different tables like above one will gather the data and the other other one will then loop through and display the data.

Comment: @DominikWillaford I think you need to update your question to state what you are trying to do. Your question explains what you did but doesn't explain the relation between a single date input and your list of records.

Comment: @jcruz I edited my question to better show what I'm actually wanting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a viewmodel to encompass your list of `LansingMileage` records and expose a single date property for your datepicker input. Your existing model (IEnumerable) by itself can only be bound to a collection of items (unless you try some hack, eg; model[0]) so its recommended you create a viewmodel that covers the requirements of the view.

For example:

```
namespace TravelSOCC.ViewModels
{
    public class LansingMileageViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<TravelSOCC.Models.LansingMileage> Records { get; set; }
        public DateTime ExpMonthYrInput { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Your view will then use the viewmodel like this:

```
@model TravelSOCC.ViewModels.LansingMileageViewModel

<h3>STATE OFFICERS COMPENSATION COMMISSION (SOCC)</h3>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{

    <table class="table">
        <tr>
            <th>Senator Information</th>
            <th>Monthly Expense Summary</th>
            <th>Expense Month/Year</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>State Senator</td>
            <td>Mileage Total:<br />Expense Total:<br /><strong>Total:</strong></td>
            <!--This will become a datepicker-->
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ExpMonthYr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", Name = "expenseDate" } })</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
<table id="LansingData" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Expense Month/Yr</th>
            <th>Travel Date</th>
            <th>Travel Type</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Records)
        {
            <tr id="">
                <!--Here is where I will create a table to display my data from the above section-->
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

From you form post you will receive an object of the same model type so you can then use the datepicker input value like this:

```
public ActionResult Test(LansingMileageViewModel model)
{
    DateTime selectedDate = model.ExpMonthYrInput;

    return View(model);
}
```

HTH

Comment: This seems like a great option, but I am running into an issue where the model.ExpMonthYr isn't being found.

Comment: @DominikWillaford in my example viewmodel I named the property `ExpMonthYrInput` (to explicitly differentiate it from yours) so you can adjust the property or reference and it should work fine.

Comment: Oh okay I see now. Thank you!

Comment: @DominikWillaford you will not regret to choose my lite solution and it's better pattern which will be widely used in your feature. This answer is not a good method, which mixed data and search options in one object but server deal with search options only.

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is that you are trying to add header inputs in front of the table, the `datepicker` might be used for filtering data.

In this case, you cannot use any properties from `Model`, because it's a `list` and the list is not your search **options** but your search **result**. so you should have a `SearchViewModel` to pass search **options** to server, you can directly use `LansingMileage` as `SearchViewModel`. So if client input something, which data will be saved in this `SearchViewModel`.

Here is example, mostly ASP.NET Core code, but it's very similar pattern with MVC5.

At the beginning of cshtml:

```
@{
   var searchModel = ViewBag.SearchModel as LansingMileage;
}
```

inside your search form:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => searchModel.ExpMonthYr, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datepicker", Name = "expenseDate" } })
```

In server side,

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Search([FromForm]LansingMileage searchModel, int page = 0, int pageSize = 15)
{
    searchModel = searchModel ?? new LansingMileage();

    var data= GetData(searchModel, page, pageSize);

    ViewBag.SearchModel = searchModel;

    return View(data);
}
```